# Code Analysis error CA1000:DoNotDeclareStaticMembersOnGenericTypes C#

Tags: c#, generics, static, code-analysis

Here is my piece of code where I am calling PageObjectBase generic class property to return the instance. This works fine, but when I run the code analysis getting following errors:

> CA1000    Remove 'PageObjectBase<T>.PageObject' from 'PageObjectBase<T>' or make it an instance member
>
> CA1000    Remove 'PageObjectBase<T>.InstanceCreation()' from 'PageObjectBase<T>' or make it an instance member

How could I resolve this error without affecting TestBase and the logic implemented in PageObjectBase?

```
public class TestBase
{           
    public T NavigateToScreenandReturnPageObject<T>() where T :class, new()
    {
        return PageObjectBase<T>.PageObject;
    }
}
    
public static class PageObjectBase<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private static T singleTonObject;

    public static T PageObject
    {
        get
        {
            return InstanceCreation();
        }
    }

    public static T InstanceCreation()
    {           
        if (singleTonObject == null)
        {
           singleTonObject = new T();
        }
        return singleTonObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: make sure your newly invented wheel is not square by carefully reading http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: Thanks all for your time.I have let it be like this ignoring the code analysis error.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything to fix here based on those warnings.  Those warnings are aimed at people that misuse static variables in generic classes while not realizing that each generic type produces a different static variable.  Your code is actually taking advantage of how static variables work in generic classes.

I would also definitely recommend you read the link Alexei recommended to fix up your singleton implementation.  http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that a static member in a generic type will not be shared among instances of different close constructed types. This means that for a generic class `MyGeneric<T>` which has `public static string MyProp { get; set; }`, the values of `MyGeneric<int>.MyProp` and `MyGeneric<string>.MyProp` have completely different, independent values.

In most of the cases these may cause runtime errors and that's why code analysis provides suggestion to avoid it.

If you still want to keep the static members on the type and keep the code analysis rule , the. I would suggest to create a non generic base class for T type of types and have static method there.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you.Could you please give an example

Comment: please refer [the article](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/10/generic-types-and-static-members.html) for code samples.

Comment: > the values of MyGeneric<int>.MyProp and MyGeneric<string>.MyProp have completely different, independent values
Why wouldn't they? They are different types.